# php conditional statement from string variable

Tags: php

I have a question on PHP if statements.
Lets say we have situation:

```
$id = 1;
$condition = "$id > 0";
if($condition){...}
```

How I can parse `$condition` variable to a an actual condition like:

```
$id = 1;
$condition = "$id > 0";
if($id > 0){...}
```

is there any simple and secure way for this?

Comment: what is your problem actually?

Comment: If you are looking to use ternary instead if..else then refer: http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Comment: @anantkumarsingh problem is i dont know how to convert string to condition

Comment: @Dainius why you want to convert string to condition, could you please tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the function called `eval`. That evaluates your string text as a php code. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

If you really want to do this, at least read the warning

> Caution The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it
>   allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged.
>   If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to
>   use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user
>   provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

<strike>Something like this should then work:</strike>

```
$id = 1;
$condition = eval("$id > 0");
if($condition){...}
```

**Edit:**

Eval expects a complete line of code, so you need to use it like this:

```
$id = -1;
$condition = eval('return $id > 0;');
if ($condition)
{
    echo 'true';
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: I read all documentation and consider this... I am a bit sceptical about this

Comment: Its giving error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in file : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: @SashantPardeshi, line one is assignement of $id.. Maybe you're doing something wrong? I'll check that..

Comment: @walther Its working fine now :)